# JAXB use Map instead of List but get XML output as if the Map's values were a List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml schema for the element type `Foos` and `Foo`:

```
<xs:complexType name="Foos">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="foo" type="foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Then the generated class for `Foos` (using xjc as described here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-generate-classes-xsd/) looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Foos", propOrder = {"foo"})
public class Foos {

    protected List<Foo> foo;

    public List<Foo> getFoo() {
        if (foo == null) {
            foo = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        }
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

If I create an instance of `Foos` called `myFoos`, fill it with two `Foo`s and print it to console using

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foos.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(myFoos, System.out);
```

then I get output according to the schema, like this:

```
<foos>
    <foo name="foo1"/>
    <foo name="foo2"/>
</foos>
```

However, to process my data in a better way, I want to use a `Map<Foo, Foo>` instead of a `List<Foo>`. But I do not want the XML output to change: I want only the VALUES of my map to be written into the XML; the KEYS should not occur at all.

**How do I do this?**

If I change the class `Foos` like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Foos", propOrder = {"foo"})
public class Foos {

    protected Map<Foo, Foo> foo;

    public Map<Foo, Foo> getFoo() {
        if (foo == null) {
            foo = new HashMap<Foo, Foo>();
        }
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

then I would get the following XML instead:

```
<foos>
    <foo>
        <entry>
            <key name="foo1"/>
            <value  name="foo1"/>
        </entry>
    </part>
    <foo>
        <entry>
            <key name="foo2"/>
            <value  name="foo2"/>
        </entry>
    </part>
</parts>
```

Comment: Given the XML `<foo name="foo1"/><foo name="foo2"/>`, what would be the keys of the Map<Foo, Foo>, and what would be the values? And in any case, why don't you simply add a method in your Foos class (or in a higher-level class) that transforms the list into a map?

Comment: As I said, the values of the Map are what should be output in the XML. Thus, for xml `<foo name="foo1"/><foo name="foo2"/>`, both `foo1` and `foo2` are values. What the keys are does not matter for my question. And if I start explaining that now, probably many more questions will come regarding why I am doing this, totally disregarding the topic of my question.

Comment: Why am I not adding a method to transform the list into a map? I want to modify and analyze the collection (i.e. the map), that is: add new elements, ask if a certain key is present, get its value. And the xml output should represent exactly the content (of the values of the map) as it is at a certain point in my program. If I create a new list from the map via a method, it will only be a copy, not showing the actual content. Right? Or is there a way to make a list which directly links to the map's values? If so, I'd be glad to ready your answer!

Comment: It will be a copy (or even a view if you just return the values of the map directly) of the values of the map at the moment the method is called, i.e. the moment the XML is generated. Of course it will show the actual content. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: So you suggest calling that method right before outputting the XML. Sure that will work, but it's not what I am looking for. I want it to just work without calling the method myself - it is an error source (forgetting to call the method right before outputting the xml) after all.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm suggesting. JAXB uses getter to serialize the state of your class. So if you have a getter that returns a List or a Set of Foos, it will serialize that List or Set. It doesn't care whether the getter returns a field, or if it creates a new List or a new Set from a map.

Comment: That does not seem to work: I used the generated class, 1. added a new `@XmlTransient` field `Map<Foo, Foo> fooMap` with a corresponding getter. 2. I changed `getFoo` to return `getFooMap().values()` and 3. changed the return type of `getFoo`and the type of field `foo` to `Collection<Foo>` accordingly. Then in my program, `foo` is always null but `getFoo` returns the values of my map. But still, XML generation does not output anything even if `fooMap` contains elements.

Comment: Have you changed the value of XmlAccessorType? It should not be FIELD, but PROPERTY, since you precisely want JAXB to cal your getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to JB Nizet for pointing me to the right direction:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Foos", propOrder = { "foo" })
public class Foos {

    private Map<Foo, Foo> fooMap;

    @XmlElements(value = { @XmlElement })
    public Collection<Foo> getFoo() {
        return getFooMap().values();
    }

    public Map<Foo, Foo> getFooMap() {
        if (fooMap == null) {
            fooMap = new HashMap<Foo, Foo>();
        }
        return this.FooMap;
    }
}
```

- I changed `XmlAccessType` to `NONE` because we are not interested in the fields any more (but in the method `getFoo` instead).
- Marked method `getFoo` with `@XmlElements` to use it in xml serialization.
- Was not able to make it work by using `XmlAccessType.PROPERTY`; if you are, please share!